# Swift - UITabBarController as ChildViewController is not working

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I need to add UITabBarController as a subview of RootViewController, but that UITabBarController can't be touched.

Here is my code. How can i fix it?

```
func addSubviewToSelf(){
    var tabVC = TabBarVC()

    addChildViewController(tabVC)

    self.view.addSubview(tabVC.view)

    tabVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)


    tabVC.view.snp.makeConstraints{ (make) in
        make.top.bottom.left.right.equalTo(self.view)
    }

}
```

Comment: I think you should try tabVC bringViewToFront method

Comment: I tried your code and it works. Only I didn't apply any constraints. If that's not the reason, then it must be something inside you TabBarVC class. Or, do you add something to root view controller after tabbar?

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't work @SachinVsSachin

Comment: @Evgeniy oh yes, i add another ViewController to RootViewController, does that matter? But the ViewController that has been added to tabVC can be touched.  I've no idea to fix this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the simplified version of adding UITabBarController as childView of UIViewController, I'm using NSLayoutAnchor API in place of SnapKit

```
import UIKit

class RootViewController: UIViewController {

    override func loadView() {
        view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        addChildVC()
    }

    func addChildVC() {
        let tabBarVC = TabBarVC()
        addChild(tabBarVC)
        view.addSubview(tabBarVC.view)
        tabBarVC.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            tabBarVC.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            tabBarVC.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            tabBarVC.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            tabBarVC.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor)
        ])
        tabBarVC.didMove(toParent: self)
    }
}
```

The `UITabBarController` subclass is below

```
class TabBarVC: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        delegate = self
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        configureTabBarItems()
    }

    func configureTabBarItems() {
        let vc1 = UIViewController()
        vc1.view.backgroundColor = .orange
        vc1.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: .search, tag: 0)

        let vc2 = UIViewController()
        vc2.view.backgroundColor = .yellow
        vc2.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: .bookmarks, tag: 1)

        let navigationController1 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc1)
        let navigationController2 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc2)
        setViewControllers([navigationController1, navigationController2], animated: false)

        tabBar.tintColor = .red
        tabBar.unselectedItemTintColor = .black
    }
}
```

As you have not given UITabBarController subclass implementation, you may create some UIViewControllers and assign it to `setViewControllers(_ viewControllers::[UIViewControllers]?, animated: Bool)` method. Also set `tintColor` and `unselectedItemTintColor` properties and check if works for you. Finally **Clean Build** project and run, it should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

If the Tabbarvc is about for all App , I think you can call in AppDelegate. Write this code in didFinishLaunch in AppDelegate

```
window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "TabBarStoryBoard", bundle: Bundle.main)
            let viewController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()
            window?.rootViewController = viewController
            window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
            return true
```